# How to break down a string into a list of dates

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Through web scraping with selenium/python 3.x I get the following list of a single string value from a dropdown list:

```
['December 18, 2019December 20, 2019December 23, 2019December 24, 2019December 27, 2019December 30, 2019December 31, 2019']
```

How can I transform this into a list of dates?

My guess (but I don't know yet how to do that) would be to go through the string and whenever I get a comma (`,`) then go 5 characters further to mark the end point of a date, and then move onto the remaining value of the string.

Moreover isn't there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: A bit of an XY problem? Perhaps you should fix the scraping code to correctly parse the "dropdown **list**" into a **list** of strings, instead of trying to parse the wrong output.

Comment: "go through the string and whenever I get a comma (,) then go 5 characters further to mark the end point of a date" - if the format is consistent enough, then surely, you can do that

Comment: "whenever I get a comma (,) then go 5 characters further" nice way to have a "Year 10000 problem" ;)

Comment: sounds like a problem with selenium or with your scraping, you should figure that out instead of treating the symptom

Comment: There's surely a better way (like fixing your scraper), but here's one way using regex: `[datetime.strptime(dt, "%B %d, %Y") for dt in re.split('(\w+ \d{1,2}, \d{4})', your_string) if dt]`.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try to fix the scrapping code indeed